# How to attach or update an API gateway resource policy using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, api-gateway

Is there any method in boto3 which will attach or update the resource policy in api -gateway?

I searched in the boto3 documentation, but didn't find any method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use the [`create_rest_api`](http://create_rest_api%60(https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.create_rest_api) method for attaching, and the [`update_rest_api`](https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/apigateway.html#APIGateway.Client.update_rest_api) method for updating. The [Create and Attach an API Gateway Resource Policy to an API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-resource-policies-create-attach.html) documentation for the CLI/API should be of help in describing the `patchOperations` values you should use to update an existing policy.

Be sure to redeploy as the documentation states:

> **Important**
>
> If you attach a resource policy to a deployed API, or if you update an existing resource policy, you'll need to redeploy the API for the changes to take effect.